# "ImportError: C extension: No module named conversion not built." while passing external dependency to PySparkShell. How to pass external depandancy?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pip

On dataproc cluster, I want to run multiple custom pyspark jobs. Every job requires different custom dependency. So instead of installing all the dependencies on cluster, I am passing external dependency as shown below

```
pyspark --py-files dependancies.zip
```

It's throwing import error

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.3.3
      /_/
Using Python version 2.7.13 (default, Sep 26 2018 18:42:22)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/hadoop/spark/tmp/spark-8cae9657-a5cf-48c4-a489-a259e0a6b46b/userFiles-600df978-7f65-40c5-a573-0189676c51cc/dependancies.zip/pandas/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
ImportError: C extension: No module named conversion not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext
 --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first.
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install 3rd party libraries like Pandas, Numpy etc like that. The libraries need to be installed on all the nodes and the way to do that would be through the cluster initialization steps.

You can refer to this link [1] which shows how to do this setup.

1 - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/blob/master/conda/README.MD

Comment: Is there a workaround to install the libraries once the cluster is set up, or just pass it as an external dependency to the spark job.

Comment: You can run the script against dataproc. You cannot pass it as a dependency.

Comment: How to execute multiple custom pyspark jobs with having a requirement of custom dependencies for each?

Comment: You would need to do this for all pip install packages once. You can collect all the requirements and put it in requirements.txt and perform the cluster setup. Any application related dependency can be passed as external dependency.

Comment: As per my above-posted code, my application-related dependency is pandas. So how to add this dependancy externally?

Comment: You cannot, you need to do pip/conda separately on all the worker nodes before submitting the pyspark job.The link has the instructions on how to do it.

Comment: But this solution will fail while running multiple jobs simultaneously. Is there any way to run multiple jobs with an associated dependency of each job?

Comment: If you don't have ephemeral Dataproc clusters then you just do the setup once and run all your jobs. If you are creating separate clusters for each job then you do init action to run the setups first and then execute your job